# no sound after ubuntu upgrade to 16.04

Tags: 16.04

no sound after ubuntu upgrade to 16.04 My ALSA information is located at http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=c2159b1567c305b77cd51d395d33dad429926dae

```
uname -r
4.4.0-112-generic

aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...

modprobe snd_hda_intel
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd_hda_intel not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-112-generic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your upgrade to 16.04 assure you issue

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

to pickup any driver updates ... Now to try to repair your existing OS issue this

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k
```

When you issue the following command

```
find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) | grep snd
```

above output should contain over 250 files looking like this

```
/lib/modules/4.4.0-122-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/snd-virmidi.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-122-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/snd-portman2x4.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-122-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/snd-serial-u16550.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-122-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/snd-mts64.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-122-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/opl3/snd-opl3-lib.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-122-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/opl3/snd-opl3-synth.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-122-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/pcsp/snd-pcsp.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-122-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/vx/snd-vx-lib.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-122-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/mpu401/snd-mpu401-uart.ko
```

if not then issue following to seed up your sound drivers

```
# sudo apt-get install linux-restricted-modules-$(uname -r) linux-generic    

sudo apt-get install linux-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libasound2 linux-sound-base alsa-utils alsa-tools
```

if output of above looks smacked then issue this to help get the packages aligned

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

you may need to reboot here ... before you reboot issue below to see if your audio is recognized now

```
lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
```

you should see something like this

```
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company FCH Azalia Controller
    Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 64, IRQ 16
    Memory at feb40000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

If not then reboot to pickup above drivers ... now audio ? If its fixed please tell us if you needed to reboot or not ?

if not then update your question with your output ... see if your sound card is getting linked to your OS by issuing

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

you should see something like this

```
0 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                  HD-Audio Generic at 0xfeb40000 irq 16
1 [D1             ]: USB-Audio - Audioengine D1
                                    2010 REV 1.7 Audioengine D1 at usb-0000:00:12.0-3, full speed
```

if not update your question with your output ... If still no go then jump into doing this   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio/Log

If you are on a laptop/desktop I would boot the machine using a liveCD of ubuntu 16.04 from either a USB stick or DVD ... download the ISO file then burn on to USB stick using unetbootin ... once booted from that known solid OS does sound now work ?  If not then its your hardware.  If good sound then your above OS is shaky and you may consider to wipe the box with a fresh ubuntu 16.04 instead of the always suspect upgrade from existing prior OS

Are you on something other than laptop/desktop like a System-on-a-Card machine ?

Comment: after upgrade linux kernel to 4.4.0-124, everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:
[Avoid missing kernel linux-modules-extra-XX-generic when updating kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265137/avoid-missing-kernel-linux-modules-extra-xx-generic-when-updating-kernel)
may help avoiding the problem in the future, in some cases.

This answer pertains to Ubuntu 20.04.
It solved my problem [Only "Dummy output" (sound) in Ubuntu 20.04 after reboot - Broken driver / module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul) (I have posted [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1259815/226614) for my own question).
I am simply posting it here just in case it helps anyone reaching this from today onward... it would have helped me having it here.

Drivers `snd_hda_intel` and related are now in loadable modules from package `linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`.

I infer from the accepted answer that at its time the corresponding package was `linux-restricted-modules-$(uname -r)`.

Otherwise, they may be [compiled in the kernel](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=snd-hda-intel&mode=filename&suite=testing&arch=amd64).